# C++ primer 5th edition: A bitset to represent a sequence of integers

Tags: c++, std-bitset

I am asked on C++ primer 5th edition this exercise:

> Exercise 17.10: Using the sequence 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, initialize a `bitset` that has a `1` bit in each position corresponding to a number in this
> sequence. Default initialize another `bitset` and write a small program to turn on each of the appropriate bits.

In fact I almost solved all the exercises of the book but I couldn't understand this. I've understood `std::bitset`.

I've found a solution like this:

```
// init from the sequence: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
std::bitset<22> bitseq("1000000010000100101110");
std::cout << bitseq << std::endl;

// Default initialize, then turn on.
std::bitset<22> bit_default;
for (auto i : {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21})
    bit_default.set(i);
std::cout << bit_default << std::endl;

assert(bitseq == bit_default);
```

But I don't know how it is this way and how it works? please help me to understand this if it is correct. Thanks guys too much!

I don't understand how can such `1000000010000100101110` represent the sequence `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21`?.

Comment: Did you write that code yourself?  Then you should already understand it.  There's nothing tricky about it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No it is not me who wrote it I've found it as a solution.

Comment: Which bit (pardon the pun) don't you understand: the `auto`, the `.set(i)` or something else?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the part you don't understand?

Comment: @AdrianMole: How can `1000000010000100101110` represent the sequence `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21`?

Comment: It doesn't.  That's not what the book is asking.  It's stating that in a `bitset<22>`, the bits `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21` should be set to `1`

Comment: Count the positions of each of the `1` characters, starting from the right, and counting from zero.

Comment: It seems the exercise text specifically explains what you're asking about. In the context of the exercise, each number in the sequence is a bit position in your bitset, where the bit is set to 1...

Comment: @NathanOliver Being picky, that is a valid representation of that sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can 1000000010000100101110 represent the sequence 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21?

Numbers in base 2 are typically *written* MSB first - most significant bit first - and typically *numbered* or *indexed* from right to left, from the least significant bit, starting from 0 (or 1).

```
1000000010000100101110
^       ^            ^-- bit with index 0  - least significant bit 2^0
^       ^           ^--- bit with index 1
^       ^          ^---- bit with index 2
^       ^         ^----- bit with index 3
^       ^        ^------ bit with index 4
^       ^       ^------- bit with index 5
^       ^      ^-------- bit with index 6
^       ^     ^--------- bit with index 7
^       ^--------------- bit with index 13
^----------------------- bit with index 21 - most significant bit 2^21
```

When numbering bit positions starting from 0 from the right side, the sequence `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21` represents set bits within the string `1000000010000100101110`.

Comment: So I can start from `1` rather than `0` to be something like this `100000001000010010111`?

Comment: Let's a real life example: When you __index__ the number of shoes, in real life you count: 1st shoe. 2nd shoe. 3rd shoe. In programming arrays start from 0: shoe __number 0__ is the first shoe, shoe _number_ 1 is the second shoe, etc. You can __index__ the bit positions starting from 1, but usually it's confusing, as array indexing starts from 0, and bitshifts work like `1<<4` is the 5th (not 4rd!) bit from the right.